# How to size up border?

Tags: css, border

Is there a way to make the border bigger than the div that it's attached to?  For example, if the div dimensions were 10x10, could I make the border 20x10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can:- check this link -  http://jsfiddle.net/QnTqh/2/

```
div{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
    border-width:200px 200px 10px 10px;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to control each side independently:

```
border-top: 10px solid #000;
border-right: 20px solid #000;
border-bottom: 10px solid #000;
border-left: 20px solid #000;
```

Or make them all the same:

```
border: 20px solid #000;
```

Comment: I want to keep the width of the border the same, but I want to make the box that the border is bordering bigger.

Comment: The border is on the outside of the div.  Make the div bigger.